# What kind of FDs or MVDs exist in 5NF?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies

From the "[A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label4.1.2)" by William Kent, Communications of the ACM 26(2), Feb. 1983, 120-125:

> The two many-to-many relationships, employee:skill and employee:language, are "independent" in that there is no direct connection between skills and languages. There is only an indirect connection because they belong to some common employee. That is, it does not matter which skill is paired with which language in a record; the pairing does not convey any information.

> Fourth and fifth normal forms both deal with combinations of multivalued facts. One difference is that the facts dealt with under fifth normal form are not independent, in the sense discussed earlier.

> Suppose that a certain rule was in effect: if an agent sells a certain product, and he represents a company making that product, then he sells that product for that company.

Relation ACP:

> The following example illustrates a case in which the rule about agents, companies, and products is satisfied, and which clearly requires all three record types [AGENT-COMPANY, COMPANY-PRODUCT and AGENT-PRODUCT] in the normalized form. Any two of the record types taken alone will imply something untrue.
>
> | AGENT | COMPANY | PRODUCT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Smith | Ford | car |
> | Smith | Ford | truck |
> | Smith | GM | car |
> | Smith | GM | truck |
> | Jones | Ford | car |
> | Jones | Ford | truck |
> | Brown | Ford | car |
> | Brown | GM | car |
> | Brown | Totota | car |
> | Brown | Totota | bus |

Will the following MVDs hold in ACP as cyclic MVDs?

```
agent->>company
agent->>product
company->>product
```

Does the rule enforced in the relation imply the multi-valued facts in ACP are not independent facts?

Does that implication imply there there is no tuple-generating dependency which exists in 4NF?

What kind of FDs or MVDs exist in 5NF?

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? (Not 3 & not a chain of "because"s.)

Comment: What is a "cyclic MVD"? What do you mean or think the quoted paper means by "multi-valued fact" & "independent fact"? These are not technical terms & are not used to define 5NF & are not clearly defined in the paper. The paper is informal. It unclearly "illustrates" its term "independent" as "there is no direct connection between skills and languages", begging the question of what a "direct connection" is & twice again unclearly rephrases in "it does not matter which skill is paired with which language in a record; the pairing does not convey any information".